# ModalPopupExtender and IE 6

Tags: modalpopupextender

I am using the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit. Within this toolkit, I am only utilizing the ModalPopupExtender (which requires a ScriptManager). This ModalPopupExtender is used on a very basic page. In fact, the page is just a login screen. If the user does not enter their login credentials, we want to show a dialog.

The ModalPopupExtender on this screen works in EVERY OTHER BROWSER, according to http://www.xenocode.com/browsers/ except for IE 6. When I load the page in IE 6, I cannot even enter any text into either the username or password fields.

What could be wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its IE6 . . . that is your problem.  If you search SO for IE6 I am sure you will find a TON of people having issues with CSS/Javascript/ and IE.  All 3 which are needed for the modal popup extender to work.

As for a solution to your problem . . . that I don't know.  I do wish I could be more help.